# How to show varchar field in format "HHmmss" as hh:mm:ss SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time

I have an old fingerprint program that keep the time of attendance from the zk machine in the format of `HHmmss`

What I need is to show it in the format of `HH:mm:ss`.

I tried many functions with different parameter such as `CONVERT` and `CAST`
with no way.

BTW in oracle it's very easy with `TO_CHAR`.

Finally I could do it with `SUBSTRING` every two letters and add ":" but it's so stupid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of `sql server` you are using

Comment: SQL 2000 TO SQL 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Stuff` + `Convert` Function.

Use `Stuff` to insert `:` in the `varchar` data and `convert` to get the required format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), Stuff(Stuff('212022', 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 8)
```

Result : `21:20:22`